# read.csv into nested list and set element names

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm reading .csv files from several different directories into a nested list. Along the lines of

```
filenames <- list(a = list.files("/some_dir_1", pattern = "*.csv"), # not a reproducible example but for demonstration purposes 
                  b = list.files("/some_dir_2", pattern = "*.csv"),
                  c = list.files("/some_dir_3", pattern = "*.csv"))
                  # creates a nested of list of file paths

dat.list <- lapply(filenames, lapply, read.csv)
            # creates a nested list of dataframes, with the same structure as filenames
```

I'd like to name each element with their file path.

This could be done by naming them one by one, e.g.

```
    names(dat.list[["a"]]) <- filenames[["a"]]
```

or by putting this in a for-loop, but is there a more versatile method? Preferably a `tidyverse` friendly solution, along the lines of...

```
filenames %>% lapply(., lapply, read_csv) %>% #some naming call#
```

Or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the description, either we can use `lapply` to loop through the sequence of 'filenames' or with `for` loop to change the `names` of each of the `dat.list[[i]]` elements

```
lapply(seq_along(filenames), function(i) setNames(dat.list[[i]], filenames[[i]]))
```

Or with `Map`

```
Map(setNames, dat.list, filenames)
```

Or

```
for(i in seq_along(filenames)) names(dat.list[[i]]) <- filenames[[i]]
```

---

If we want to use `tidyverse`, the equivalent option based on `base R` `Map` would be

```
library(purrr)
map2(dat.list, filenames, setNames)
```

NOTE: The `for` loop assignment will reflect on the original 'dat.list', while we have to assign the `lapply` back to `dat.list` to update the 'dat.list'

#### data

```
filenames <- list(a = c('a1.csv', 'a2.csv'), b = c('b1.csv', 'b2.csv'))
set.seed(24)
dat.list <- lapply(1:2, function(i) replicate(2, as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5, 5*5, 
        replace = TRUE), 5, 5)), simplify = FALSE))
```

Comment: An excellent answer, and `map2()` is exactly the thing I was looking for. Thank you